# Adding a fading color only to 3D curves going outside a cylinder

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, parametric-functions, generative-art

I'm having a problem with color shades on multi curves drawn with the **Mathematica 7.0** code below.  All the curves with both their endpoints inside the unit cylinder (green circle on the picture below) are okay.  But the curves which are going outside have a free ending that should gently fade away.  The code should do this for any **alpha** angle, all values of **omega** < 1, and *any value to the **NCourbes** parameter*.

Here's the working code :

```
alpha = 45Pi/180;

omega = 0.2;

r[x_,y_,z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]

Mu0[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {Cos[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], Sin[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], Cos[alpha]}

Mu1[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {-Sin[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], Cos[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], 0}

Mu2[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {-Cos[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], -Sin[t-r[x,y,z]]Sin[alpha], 0}

Bdipolaire[t_,x_,y_,z_] := 3(Mu0[t,x,y,z].{x,y,z}){x,y,z}/r[x,y,z]^5 - Mu0[t,x,y,z]/r[x,y,z]^3

Binduction[t_,x_,y_,z_] := 3(Mu1[t,x,y,z].{x,y,z}){x,y,z}/r[x,y,z]^4 - Mu1[t,x,y,z]/r[x,y,z]^2

Bradiation[t_,x_,y_,z_] := 1 (Mu2[t,x,y,z].{x,y,z}){x,y,z}/r[x,y,z]^3 - Mu2[t,x,y,z]/r[x,y,z]

Btotal[t_,x_,y_,z_] := Bdipolaire[t,x,y,z] + Binduction[t,x,y,z] + Bradiation[t,x,y,z]

NormeB[t_,x_,y_,z_] := Sqrt[Btotal[t,x,y,z].Btotal[t,x,y,z]]

Bx[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {1,0,0}.Btotal[t,x,y,z]
By[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {0,1,0}.Btotal[t,x,y,z]
Bz[t_,x_,y_,z_] := {0,0,1}.Btotal[t,x,y,z]

NCourbes = 26;

phi[n_] := n 2Pi/NCourbes

CourbeMagnetique[n_] := NDSolve[{
    x'[s] == Bx[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]],
    y'[s] == By[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]],
    z'[s] == Bz[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[omega,x[s],y[s],z[s]],
    x[0] == Cos[phi[n]],
    y[0] == Sin[phi[n]],
    z[0] == 0
},{x,y,z},{s,-20,20},Method->Automatic,MaxSteps->10000000, StoppingTest->(Sqrt[x[s]^2+y[s]^2+z[s]^2]<omega||Sqrt[x[s]^2+y[s]^2+z[s]^2] >5)]

Do[CourbeMagnetique[n], {n,1,NCourbes}]

Smin[n_] := (x/.CourbeMagnetique[n])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
Smax[n_] := (x/.CourbeMagnetique[n])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]

Couleur1 = RGBColor[0,0,1];
Couleur2 = RGBColor[0.70,0.60,0.40];
Couleur3 = RGBColor[1,0,0];

GrapheMagnetique[n_] := ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[s],y[s],z[s]}/.CourbeMagnetique[n]],{s,Smin[n],Smax[n]},PlotStyle->{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]]}, ColorFunction->(Blend[{Couleur1,Couleur2,Couleur3},#4]&)]

CercleLumiere = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p],Sin[p],0},{p,0,2Pi}, PlotStyle->{Directive[Thick,RGBColor[0.40,0.70,0.40]]}];

Pulsar = Graphics3D[Sphere[{0,0,0},omega]];

Graphique = Show[Table[GrapheMagnetique[n],{n,1,NCourbes}], CercleLumiere,Pulsar,PlotRange->All]
```

Here's a picture showing what the code above is doing :
[image: my picture]

As you can see, there are several curves going outside the cylinder, and their free ending (in blue or red) is ugly.  How to make them gently fade away to white ?

I guess that a condition like $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ should be added somewhere, but I can't see what exactly.

Take note that I'm working with **Mathematica 7.0**.

**EDIT :** I simplified a bit the code above.

**EDIT 2 :** From wxffles's solution below, I'm now getting this sweetness :

[image: my picture]

Comment: Please post a MINIMAL example instead of dumping all your code here ... There are a lot of nuisances unrelated to your current problem in there

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't had the impression that the code is that long.  I'll simplify it.

Comment: You need only one function definition and one `ParametricPlot3D` to show the problem: just two expressions.The rest is meaningless for solving your issue.

Comment: I don't think so.  I need to show various field lines ; some with their endpoints closed on the central sphere, and some going outside with a free end.  For the rest of the code, I don't see what could be simplified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just make a function which decides your end colour:

```
colour1[n_] := 
 With[{end = {x[s], y[s], z[s]} /. First@CourbeMagnetique[n] /. s :> Smin[n]},
  If[Norm@end < 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 1, 1]]]

colour3[n_] := 
 With[{end = {x[s], y[s], z[s]} /. First@CourbeMagnetique[n] /. s :> Smax[n]},
  If[Norm@end < 1, RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 1]]]
```

And change your `ColorFunction` to match:

```
Blend[{colour1[n], Couleur2, colour3[n]}, #4] &
```

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work.  I'm getting several error messages like this one : "Blend::arg:{Couleur1[1],RGBColor[0,0,1],Couleur3[1]} is not a valid list of color or gray-level directives, or pairs of a real number and a directive.".  Are you sure that these commands are compatible with **Mathematica 7.0** ?

Comment: No, it's working !!  I just made a stupid typo in the code ! 8-)  Wow, this is fantastic !  Thanks a lot wxffles !